# Using Dapper to populate Enum properties

Tags: c#, enums, dapper

In using Dapper's Query() function, I am trying to fill in a class that has a property which is an enumerated value.  In my database, this column is stored as a byte.  However, in the class, they are an enum.  In the old ADO.NET approach, I'd convert during the reader loop:

```
myClass.myEnum = (MyEnumType) reader.GetByte(2);
```

When using Dapper, I can't figure out how to do this conversion.  For example when I do something like

```
myClass = conn.Query<MyClassType>("SELECT ... ")
```

I get an error of the type

```
Error parsing column 2 (myEnum=1 - Byte)
```

Is there a way to use Dapper's Query() to fill in a class that contains properties which are enum types?

Comment: Note that if the datatype in SQLITE is "INT", then no special code is required to persist and retrieve .NET enums from Sqlite using Dapper.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sure - as long as your enum agrees, i.e.

```
enum MyEnumType : byte {
    Foo, Bar, Blip, ...
}
```

then it will all work automatically.

(this limitation is by design, and shared with LINQ-to-SQL as it happens)

Alternatively, if the enum is `: int` and can't be changed, cast it in the SQL:

```
SELECT ..., CAST(x.myEnum as int) as myEnum, ...
```

Or finally, use the `dynamic` API:

```
foreach(var row in conn.Query(...)) { // note no <T>
    T obj = new Item { /* copy from row */ };
    ...
}
```

---

The first is my preferred object, as that enforces the `byte` data-type limitation throughout all your code, which is IMO a good thing.

Comment: That worked!  I was unaware that the in-memory storage type made such a difference.  Thank you!

Comment: Careful, this can be dangerous if you don't explicitly set the values for your enums.  You want to do enum MyEnumType : byte { Foo = 1, Bar = 2, Blip = 3, ... }  If not, some junior developer will come behind you and insert Biz between Foo & Bar and redefine the values of anything after Biz.  Those database values are now wrong.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but is a little unfortunate with respect to SQLite, which reports all integers as 64-bit numbers (meaning all `enum`s have to inherit `long` even if they only have a handful of values). I guess that's more of a limitation of SQLite than Dapper though :-)

Comment: @Cameron https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/9b0808d441d535fe6395c9241f3d82deb0ee8698

Comment: @Cameron as far as I can see, just about everything now maps cleanly to just about everything